# TypeScript to infer type arguments in interface implementation class

Tags: typescript

It will complain that type of `arg` is `any`

```
interface Foo { 
  foo(arg: string): void 
}

class FooImpl implements Foo {
  foo(arg) { console.log(arg) }
}
```

I can of course specify that it's `string` but it's repetitive.

Maybe there's a way to tune TypeScript to make it infer that it's `string` automatically?

Comment: Agree, it is a missing feature in TypeScript. However, it is not that simple, as you can implement multiple interfaces with the same `foo` function with different arguments. Some signature merging is needed.

Comment: I think the whole "infer" thing does not match with what is typescript being designed for. In typescript everything needs to be strongly typed unlike javascript where you can "assume" the datatype for any variable/arg depending on the declaration.

Comment: @Niladri Typescript infers correctly in a whole bunch of quite complicated cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is TypeScript unable to infer the type of function parameters when implementing a generic interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718470/why-is-typescript-unable-to-infer-the-type-of-function-parameters-when-implement)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Maybe there's a way to tune TypeScript to make it infer that it's string automatically

No. Here is the relevant TypeScript issue with reasons why its not there: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373

Comment: Digging deeper: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207 has a more concrete discussion.