# Infer function parameter types when implementing interface

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble understanding why the following doesn't work for inferring function parameter types. My understanding is that setting a return type may have an influence on this, but that did not work in this scenario. What am I doing incorrectly?

```js
namespace appModel {
  export type LoadStates = null | "loading" | "success" | "not_found"

  export interface LoadState {
    loadState: LoadStates
    setLoading(state: LoadStates): void
  }

  export interface Model<T> {
    attributes: T
    update(attributes: Partial<T>): void
  }
}

interface ModelProps {
  name: string
}

class Foo implements appModel.LoadState, appModel.Model<ModelProps> {
  loadState = null
  attributes: ModelProps = { name: 'Joe' }

  setLoading(state) { // <---- warning on implicit any
    this.loadState = state
  }

  update(attributes) { // <---- warning on implicit any
    this.attributes = attributes
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript to infer type arguments in interface implementation class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038924/typescript-to-infer-type-arguments-in-interface-implementation-class)

Comment: Hmm, ok. Yes, I guess that is it! However that is disappointing, since it makes using types really repetitive. Thank you for finding that.