# Infer method argument from another property

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm trying to infer a zod schema of another property to be used as a argument type in a method. (Zod is a typescript-first validation library that lets you infer types based on the zod schema object using the z.infer util - https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod)

This is a boiled-down version of what I'm trying to do:

```
import { z } from 'zod';
import type { ZodSchema } from 'zod';

interface IHandler {
  validationSchema: ZodSchema;

  handler(params: z.infer<this['validationSchema']>): number;
}

class Handler implements IHandler {
  validationSchema = z.object({
    id: z.number(),
    token: z.string().nullable(),
  });

  handler(params) { // params is any here

    return 42;
  }
}
```

In constrast, manually typing the "params" param works:

```
import { z } from 'zod';
import type { ZodSchema } from 'zod';

interface IHandler {
  validationSchema: ZodSchema;

  handler(params: z.infer<this['validationSchema']>): number;
}

class Handler implements IHandler {
  validationSchema = z.object({
    id: z.number(),
    token: z.string().nullable(),
  });

  handler(params: z.infer<this['validationSchema']>) { // params is validly typed as { id: number, token: string | null }
    return 42;
  }
}
```

Is this a limitation in typescript or am I doing something wrong? I couldn't find any related answers, so apologies if this is a duplicat.e

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript to infer type arguments in interface implementation class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038924/typescript-to-infer-type-arguments-in-interface-implementation-class)

Comment: Turn on `noImplicitAny` if you can.